# Phonegap navigator.device issue android

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

I have some problems with camera and geolocation in my app.
WHen i try to use navigator.camera.getPicture or navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition,
happens nothing. 
Here is my code

```
options.sourceType = navigator.camera.DestinationType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
options.destinationType navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.FILE_URI;

alert(1);
navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function (data) { // Success!
                alert(4);
                self._mediaDataSuccess(data);
            }
            ,
            function (error) { // Fail!
                alert(5);
                self._mediaDataFail(error);
            },
            options
        );
alert(2);
```

At first i see message box with 1, then with 2. I haven't see 4 or 5. 
All permissions enabled.

Also, i have same code for navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, with same problem.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: It is an asynchronous function call, hence execution won't wait for success or failure to happen and that's the reason for you getting the alert as 2. If you things to execute after the execution of the function. Write them in callback functions.

Comment: According to documentation, navigator.camera.getPicture should call native application. For example, photo library, or camera. But it not works for me.

Comment: Just making sure that you're doing all of this only after ondeviceready right?

Comment: I'm using embedded cordovawebwiev, that's why i have this error. 
But how i can fix it?