# navigator.device is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, navigator

I have a script that I created to capture the camera stream but I'm getting an undefined when I try to do "navigator.device".  Here is some example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
        <button onclick="myTest();"> TEST</button>
        <p id="capture-result"><i>&lt;results go here&gt;</i></p>
        <script>
            var resdev = document.getElementById('capture-result');

            function myTest(){
                resdev.innerHTML = "<br>&lt;Looking...&gt;<hr/>";
                var str = "";
                var x;
                checkResults("1", (navigator                == undefined));
                checkResults("2", (navigator.device         == undefined));
                checkResults("3", (navigator.device.capture == undefined));
            }

            function checkResults(name, truefalse) {
                resdev.innerHTML += name + "-";
                resdev.innerHTML += (truefalse) ? "UNDEFINED" : "OK";
                resdev.innerHTML += "<br>";
            }     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get an 'undefined' error on the checkResults for 'navigator.device'.

Comment: What did you mean by device : Mobile , tablet ?

Comment: navigator.device.capture seems like PhoneGap (or Cordova) to me, not sure you can do that like that just with javascript

Answer (score 0):

When I google for **"navigator.device"** I get, among other things, [PhoneGap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html).

There is also an (old/unanswered) SO question [Phonegap navigator.device issue android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16977066/17300).

You will need PhoneGap to do what you're trying to do.

---

EDIT

As for many things, you can use feature detection an load phonegap only if the browser doesn't natively support it.

The basic concept is to test, such as `if (navigator.device == udefined) { doSomethingToLoad(phonegap); }`

I personally use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for most of this type of task.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I didn't realize that it was a PhoneGap thing.  Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: But wait!  The W3 specs specifically call out something called "navigator.device" (3.1 of [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/#devicecapture-interface))

Comment: Sorry, the link should be: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/#devicecapture-interface

Comment: Look at section 3.1 in this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/#devicecapture-interface

Comment: @user1588174-Andy - Right, but that's a "working draft" not (yet) a specification, and even if it was you would need to wait for browsers to catch up to support it.  What you can do is (see my edit to my answer)